# Android ParseFacebookUtils.login callback, returning user with null objectId

Tags: android, facebook, parse-platform

my issue is basically the same as this one: https://www.parse.com/questions/parseusers-object-id-is-null-after-logging-in-using-facebook, but there were no real answers in that thread.

If ParseFacebookUtils creates the user the first time with login(), everything works fine.
However, when I call ParseFacebookUtils.login() again, it returns a user which has a null getObjectId()

My login button: (updated)

```
    mFacebookBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ParseFacebookUtils.logIn(LoginActivity.this, new LogInCallback() {
                @Override
                public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException err) {
                    if (err != null) {
                        err.printStackTrace();
                        return;
                    }
                    if (user != null) {
                        if (user.getObjectId() == null) {
                            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Weird error where object Id is null... " + user.getObjectId() + " " + user.getUsername() + " " + user.getCreatedAt() + " " + user.getUpdatedAt(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            Log.e(TAG, "Weird error where object Id is null... " + user.getObjectId() + " " + user.getUsername() + " " + user.getCreatedAt() + " " + user.getUpdatedAt());
                        }
                            else
                            proceedToMainActivity();

                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

As I said before, if user is created the first time, it returns valid object Ids, but the second time login() is called, the Log shows that weird error

I am using Facebook SDK 3.15.0, Parse 1.5.1, and have the Facebook app also installed on the device.

Update:
This problem is still occurring, but I noticed it doesn't happen if I completely reinstall the app. However, when you logout, then on login it will still happen. Here is my logout code if it might help:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    } else if (id == R.id.action_logout) {
        ParseUser.logOut();
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Update: apparently this is a bug https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/229876443869758/ and it is still an ongoing problem for me

Comment: You can log back in ok once the app has been removed from recents. Of course it's poor UX to ask users to close app, remove from recents and relaunch - but that's that only work around I found.

Comment: I'm also getting this issue. Even with the Parse Facebook login tutorial app, the user object is always returned with an empty objectId field.

Comment: FB Bug says its only with local data store enabled but I get this even with local data store disabled. Also clearing from recents or clearing data from device also wont help. Also if I try logging in with some other phone, even that wont work. Help!

Answer (score 0):

Login to Facebook developer site and in your app dashboard under settings, check if right key hashes and package names are stored and make sure "Single Sign On" is on. Read [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started/#create-app) about key hash.

If you can log-in the user correctly for once, try to delete user and clear session before logging out.

```
ParseUser user = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();

if(user != null)
    user.deleteInBackground();
if(ParseFacebookUtils.getSession()!=null)
    ParseFacebookUtils.getSession().closeAndClearTokenInformation();

ParseUser.logOut();
```

Comment: Have you tried this? doesn't work for me, AFAIK ParseUser.logout() does that same thing. Is does feel like the cause something isn't getting closed/cleared.

Answer (score 0):

**One important thing!**
FacebookLogin Activity needs to come back (history) to the initiator activity.
If you have noHistory=true in your Activity definition in manifest Facebook wont be able to return.

**WRONG**

```
<activity
   android:name=".LoginActivity"
   android:label="Login activity"
   android:noHistory="true">
</activity>
```

**GOOD!**

```
<activity
       android:name=".LoginActivity"
       android:label="Login activity">
</activity>
```

Now in your *LoginActivity.java* You can do:

```
 ParseFacebookUtils.logIn(this, new LogInCallback() {
                @Override
                public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException err) {
                    //here you will receive the user!!!
                }
            });
```